# Show the mob health in the multiplayer mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are there any mods which can be used to show health of mobs in Minecaft? I tried to use [Mob Health Bar](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/977227-jackfirecrackers-mods-zombie-hunt-extra-big-ass-villages-and-more/) and [Show Health](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/694505-125-show-health/) but they don't work in the multiplayer mode. I also installed the [MobHealth](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/mobhealth/files/32-mob-health-v4-8-1/) bukkit plugin but it's useless since it shows health in the chat bar but not under mobs heads.

Comment: Since I Don't Have A Server To Confirm If It Works I Won't Put This As A Answer Try This Mod [Click Me](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1184887-124125-mob-info-v10/page__p__14494289#entry14494289)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work properly. The mod shows health as Mob Health Bar and Show Health but it either doesn't decrease the health stats of enemies when I hit them.

Comment: Does Spoutcraft include mob health? I know it includes player health

Comment: looking for it too...If you find it, remember to tell me....
(forgive my poor English)

Answer (score 1):

There is a mod (actually something of a complete overhaul) for Minecraft called [Hack/Mine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1183432-minecraft-hack-mine-hack-slash-mine/) that shows the health of mobs.